# How to route from site.com/home to site.com/home.html (remove .html) in htaccess?

Tags: html

Many sites have URL addresses like this:

```
youtube.com/watch
```

Not `youtube.com/watch.html`.

For example, stack overflow now shows: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`, not `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.html` or `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.php` etc. How to do this in (simple site hosting) .htaccess (or another file, I only heard it was done in htaccess)

I think you should understand my question.
There are many posts about it already, but I couldn't find a one that fits my needs and works. Thanks.

Comment: what would fit exactly your need? I found a lot of answers in this topic with a simple google search

https://www.plothost.com/kb/how-to-remove-php-html-extensions-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove .html extension use:

```
#remove html file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.html will 
become https://example.com/file
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

You should be able to read the above and figure out how to remove other extensions